# Source Code Android APP

Tags: ros, rosandroid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i was working through the tutorials of RosJava and RosAndroid.
Unluckily the result wasn't what i expected. Since i am new to Ros and to Android i had some troubles.
My Goal is to have an Android app, that is displaying a message that is published by a ros node in my PC.
I was able to do the Java PubSub Tutorial, so i am able to publish a message.

Can someone provide me with the source code of an app, in which i can visualize this message?
The Master Uri for the Master Chooser can be coded directly into the APP, there is no need to have it set by the user.

I would love to have such a project that i can just import into my Eclipse and run on my device.

Best Thanks in advance

Stefan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186938/source-code-android-app/) by [stefan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19765/stefan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-07-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ronniea](https://answers.ros.org/users/33960/ronniea/) on 2018-03-03**:
Android App Source Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i think you will find some useful information [here](http://rosjava.github.io/android_core/latest/).
One of the tutorial apps is actually a publisher/subscriber and can be found [here](https://github.com/rosjava/android_core/tree/hydro/android_tutorial_pubsub)

I hope this gets you started.

bajo

---

Originally posted by [bajo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1949/bajo/) with karma: 206 on 2014-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stefan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19765/stefan/) on 2014-07-21**:
thanks - i allready tried to work with these.

for my windows environment i downloaded
https://github.com/rosjava/android_core/tree/hydro
is there a way to import this into my android studio or better eclipse?

is there any step-by-step description what to do to import existing ros_android apps?